# A difficulty in understanding Theorem 4.1 in Stein & Shakarachi Fourier Analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]Before proving the theorem the writer said that:"The weight distribution concentrates its mass at y=0 as n becomes large" but I do not know why? could anyone explain this for me please?

[image]

Comment: This question isn't very accessible to those of us who don't have this book handy. Can you provide a bit more background please?

Comment: Why don't you write out the theorem and all relevant information for those of us who don't have access to the book.

Comment: @Mattos okay I will do

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Ok I will do

Comment: You can take cropped screenshots rather than capture the whole screen ;)

Comment: @symplectomorphic  Ok next time I will do this.

Comment: Presumably the answer to your question is in the definition of "family of good kernels": look up that phrase in the text.

Comment: I have looked at the definition but I couldn`t see the answer @symplectomorphic

Comment: Then you didn't read closely enough. The statement is captured by part (c) of the definition on page 48 (in my edition, at least).

Comment: @symplectomorphic thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of *good kernel*, the sequence $(K_n)_n$ satisfies
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi K_n(y) dy = 1 \text{ for all }n
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\delta\leq|y|\leq\pi} |K_n(y)| dy = 0 \text{ for all } \delta>0.
\end{eqnarray}

This is what the author describes as *"The weight distribution concentrates its mass at $y=0$ as $n$ becomes large"*.